# Data Conversion Error while applying a function to each row in pandas Python

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a data frame in pandas in python which resembles something like this -

```
    contest_login_count  contest_participation_count  ipn_ratio
0                    1                            1   0.000000
1                    3                            3   0.083333
2                    3                            3   0.000000
3                    3                            3   0.066667
4                    5                           13   0.102804
5                    2                            3   0.407407
6                    1                            3   0.000000
7                    1                            2   0.000000
8                   53                           91   0.264151
9                    1                            2   0.000000
```

Now I want to apply a function to each row of this dataframe The function is written as this -

```
def findCluster(clusterModel,data):
    return clusterModel.predict(data)
```

I apply this function to each row in this manner -

```
df_fil.apply(lambda x : findCluster(cluster_all,x.reshape(1,-1)),axis=1)
```

When I run this code, I get a warning saying -

> DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype object was converted to float64.
>
> warnings.warn(msg, DataConversionWarning)

This warning is printed once for each row. Since, I have around 450K rows in my data frame, my computer hangs while printing all these warning messages that too on ipython notebook.

But to test my function I created a dummy dataframe and tried applying the same function on that and it works well. Here is the code for that -

```
t = pd.DataFrame([[10.35,100.93,0.15],[10.35,100.93,0.15]])
t.apply(lambda x:findCluster(cluster_all,x.reshape(1,-1)),axis=1)
```

The output to this is -

```
   0  1  2
0  4  4  4
1  4  4  4
```

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong or what can I change to make this error go away?

Comment: What is `df_fil.info()` ? Maybe some column is not `float`.

Comment: @jezrael Can you add it as an answer. This worked! :)

Comment: Sure, I add it to answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think there is problem `dtype` of some column is not `float`.

You need cast it by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['colname'] = df['colname'].astype(float)
```