# scikit-learn - TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataset=pd.read_csv("/Users/rushirajparmar/Downloads/Social_network_Ads.csv",error_bad_lines = False)


X = dataset.iloc[:,[2,3]].values.  
Y = dataset.iloc[:,4].values

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size =  0.25,random_state = 0) 

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(X_train,Y_train)

y_pred = classifier.fit(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(Y_test, y_pred)
```

I just started practising LogisticRegression where I am getting this error.I can not understand what is wrong.I tried searching it on internet but it didn't help

```
y_pred = classifier.fit(X_test).values.ravel()

TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Below is the link for dataset:

https://github.com/Avik-Jain/100-Days-Of-ML-Code/blob/master/datasets/Social_Network_Ads.csv

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is this dot at the end of this line `X = dataset.iloc[:,[2,3]].values.`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already fitted the training data in `classifier.fit(X_train,Y_train)`. `classifier` being your model, now you want to predict the `y` values (`y_pred`) for the test `X` data. Hence what you need to do is

```
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

But what you are doing is

```
y_pred = classifier.fit(X_test)
```

Hence you are getting the error `fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'` because while fitting you also need the dependent variable `y` here.

Just replace `.fit` by `.predict` in the above mentioned line.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your help! I solved the error however I got an another one regarding the data type conversion as stated below; can you please help me out?                            

DataConversionWarning: Data with input dtype int64 was converted to float64 by StandardScaler.
  warnings.warn(msg, DataConversionWarning)


I tried searching on the net but couldn't find anything relevant

Comment: It's a warning, not an error. Try going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39214164/data-conversion-error-while-applying-a-function-to-each-row-in-pandas-python) link

Comment: ThankYou once again!!

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to *fit again* your classifier with your test data:

```
y_pred = classifier.fit(X_test)
```

which is of course not possible without passing also the labels (hence the error for missing `y`); I assume that what you actually want to do is to *get predictions* for your test data, in which case you shoud use [`predict`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict), and not `fit`:

```
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Sorry, I happen to have posted my answer just 15-20 seconds later than yours. We were writing in parallel universes :)

Comment: @Bazingaa Sure, not problem - such things happen :)

Comment: Thankyou very much!I got the error and it's solved now!!